# Allow a href links to phone number in owasp HtmlPolicyBuilder

Tags: java, owasp, html-sanitizing

I am trying to properly configure owasp HtmlPolicyBuilder so that it does not remove `a href tel` from a sample String like this `<p><a href="tel:8888888888">Phone number</a></p>`. This is what I have currently:

```
PolicyFactory policy = new HtmlPolicyBuilder()
   .allowCommonBlockElements()
   .allowStandardUrlProtocols()
   .allowElements("a")
   .allowAttributes("href").onElements("a")
   .toFactory();
```

But what I end up with after using this is just: `<p>Phone number</p>`. `a href` is completely removed.

What else needs to be added/modified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured out what I am missing:

`.allowUrlProtocols("tel")`